cannot get useradd to use LDAP
The OS is Amazon Linux 2023.  I am trying to use LDAP to do user/group management for all new users.  I've installed openldap-servers, openldap-clients and nss-pam-ldapd packages.  I've configured SSL on slapd and
ldapwhoami -x -H ldaps://myserver.mydomain.com
ldapwhoami -x -H ldapi:///

both return anonymous.
sudo ldapwhoami -H ldapi:///

returns dn:gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth.
I've set nsswitch.conf to:
passwd:       ldap sss files
shadow:       ldap files
group:        ldap sss files

I've set nslcd.conf to:
uid root
gid root
uri ldapi:///
base dc=mydomain,dc=com

When I run:
sudo useradd -b /home balaguru1

it does not appear to add the user to the LDAP db.  The files in /var/lib/ldap/ are unchanged.  /etc/passwd is modified with the new user.
What am I missing?

Note that normally you don’t want (root on) one compromised server to be able to create new users in your central user directory. That would provide an attacker that penetrates one server with the means to create their own valid accounts and any group membership, which then easily allows them to penetrate your complete network. - You manage ldap users with tools//scripts that authenticate to the ldap server and not necessarily the conventional command line tools used to manage local system users

@HBruijn: In general yes, but OP is testing directly on the same system that hosts the LDAP service (i.e. I interpret their example as "sudo on DB server", not "sudo on member server"), and in that situation it's fairly normal to map the OS 'root' (uid 0) to the OpenLDAP superuser via Unix socket credentials (the same is commonly done in MariaDB or Postgres), which isn't much of a security risk as root can just as well slapadd any data directly into the backend storage. Likewise most Kerberos implementations provide a kadmin.local that lets 'root' manage accounts by default.

The nsswitch interface is read-only – it doesn't have any add or modify operations that the name service modules could provide, and all such tools perform modifications directly to the backend.
For example, your useradd tool has been written specifically to update the local account database through /etc/passwd & /etc/shadow and nothing else. (Indeed it comes from the 'shadow' package which is solely for maintaining the passwd/shadow/group files.)
You will need a different tool for LDAP account management.¹

¹ (I don't know of any that would be still maintained; I ended up more-or-less writing my own. A shell script around ldapadd would work.)

it appears that my implementation does not have a schema that supports standard unix user fields. For example, when I dump cn=config there is no concept of a home directory or shell in the schema

Typical LDAP implementations are designed to have configurable schema; OpenLDAP ships with several traditional schema configs under /etc/(open)ldap/schema.
You're looking for the posixAccount objectClass, which – as you've already found – is in the nis schema file. However, it is an auxiliary class, and usually attached to a person or inetOrgPerson object (from the cosine schema in this case); although nothing stops you from attaching it to a device object or an applicationProcess object. (The latter is an OSI & X.500 relic but is somewhat fitting for representing e.g. a service that needs its own LDAP password and/or its own POSIX account.)

I tried creating a user with an ldif file but I get a "No such object (32)" error. I assume this is because the ou that I reference (People and Group) do not exist.

Yes, and you'll have to create the "parent" entries before you can put anything underneath. If you just started with an empty database, you'll need to create even the toplevel entry corresponding to your database suffix (e.g. dc=example,dc=org as an objectClass: domain entry, or o=My Little Org as an organization entry). Then create OUs as organizationalUnit objects – although it's not required to put users and groups under OUs; it's okay to create them under the toplevel entry; they can be moved into an OU later anyway.
(Note that you only have to add parents up to the DB suffix – you do not need to add dc=org in this example.)
Let's say you have a database entry configured like this:
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcSuffix: o=Widgets Corp

This means you would need to create these entries (assuming you want the typical OU=Users kind of hierarchy):
dn: o=Widgets Corp
objectClass: organization

dn: ou=People,o=Widgets Corp
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=Fred Foobar,ou=People,o=Widgets Corp
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
cn: Fred Foobar
givenName: Fred
sn: Foobar
uid: fredfoo
uidNumber: 1001
gidNumber: 1000
homeDirectory: /home/fredfoo
[...]

Whereas if you had olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com (AD-style), you would need to add:
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: domain

dn: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: uid=fredfoo,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: [...]

(If all programs support the "bind as app, search, bind as user" model, then whether to use dn: cn= or dn: uid= for the user entry's DN is your choice. Most programs are fine with this, as it's what Active Directory does. But if some programs only support "bind as uid=%s,ou=Users,etc according to a DN template" model, then you'll need to use uid=.)

thank you for the response.  I misunderstood the useradd manpage.  I have been trying ldapadd but it appears that my implementation does not have a schema that supports standard unix user fields.  For example, when I dump cn=config there is no concept of a home directory or shell in the schema.  I see uid, uidNumber, gidNumber and userPassword but that's pretty much it.  I'm about to scrap LDAP all together.  I just need an authentication system that can be accessed by VPN in the DMZ and email, mattermost, sshd and home-grown apps within the intranet.

Schema is customizable, as part of LDAP design – OpenLDAP comes with both variants of the NIS or POSIX account schema under /etc/(open)ldap/schema. Most of those aren't loaded by default.

I added the cosine, nis and inetorgperson schemas.  I tried creating a user with an ldif file but I get a "No such object (32)" error.  I assume this is because the ou that I reference (People and Group) do not exist.  I attempted to create an organization prior to attempting to create the ou records with the same error message.

Yes, you'll need create the parent objects before you can create anything underneath them. (OUs are objectClass: organizationalUnit.) Users don't necessarily have to go into an OU though – if the directory is going to be small, it's usually fine to create user objects directly under your root object; they can always be moved later (e.g. if it turns out that some app insists on having an OU specified).

I'd also recommend installing Apache Directory Studio; it's a bit more convenient than manual CLI usage (at least for management – I still use :w !ldapadd from Nvim to create new entries).

Is it required to create a new database for these user accounts?  My default installation has databases for frontend, config, monitor and mdb.  What does the dn line look like for creating an object under a root object.  I tried just deleting ou=Group and ou=People and I get the same error.

Then olcDatabase={1}mdb is the already created database for your regular entries, and that entry's olcSuffix: should tell you the top-level DN that it was configured for (which is the first entry that you'll need to ldapadd).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
